# Virtuemart Configuration - appearance issue

Tags: joomla1.5, virtuemart

I am running Virtuemart 1.1.9 on top of Joomla 1.5.25, when I attempt to edit my Virtuemart configuration, the page displays like the image below...  When I look at the same page on a different server, the tabs (Global,Security,Site, etc) are there, along with the Save/Apply/Cancel buttons.

AHIA,
LarryR...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the clue lies in "When I look at the same page on a different server".  You're missing some stylesheet(s) and possibly some image or folderss on the server that you're getting this on.  These are the typical places that they lie, so compare them on the server that is displaying it properly.

```
yourroot\components\com_virtuemart\shop_image\ps_image\
yourroot\components\com_virtuemart\themes\default\
```

and possibly:

```
yourroot\images\M_images
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some stylesheets (css files) and/or some images on the server that displays the incorrect formatting.  In order to determine which files are missing:

1. Use Chrome
2. Open the incorrectly formatted page
3. Press F12 to open Developer Tools
4. Click the [Network] tab
5. Press F5 to reload the page
6. See Chrome's Developer Tools populate a list of files that are being called for that page. In the list, look for any Status code 404 or Status code failed which tells that the file was call but not found.
7. Obtain the missing files from the other server which displays the same page with correct formatting -> upload them to the server in question -> reload the page.
8. Have a drink